# How do I return a Stream from an Extension method without breaking the Destructor?

Tags: c#, serialization, arrays, extension-methods, protobuf-net

I want to convert a `byte[]` into a stream, and have this function as an Extension method as I need to perform this hundreds of times.

```
using(MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) {
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(m, fiveHundredBytesHere);
    m.Seek(0, 0);
}
```

What is the correct way to clean up my code from this repetitive action?

Comment: You don't. If you need to use the stream later, then don't use the `using` construct and Dispose of it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

"How do I return a Stream from an Extension method without breaking the Destructor?"

You could either create a callback in the method that uses your stream that wouldnt break the Destructor, or omit the using statement and return the stream and dispose it in the calling code.

Comment: a callback method would be a horrible choice.